# How to monitor number of syscalls executed by kernel?

Tags: linux, statistics, kernel, monitoring, system-calls

I need to monitor amount of system calls executed by Linux.
I'm aware that vmstat has ability to show this for BSD and AIX systems, but for Linux it can't (according to man page).

Is there any counter in `/proc`? Or is there any other way to monitor it?

Comment: [strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace) `-c`  maybe?

Comment: Nit: The *kernel* does not execute any syscalls - it is already at the system level and therefore just calls the appropriate functions directly.

Comment: thanks. I really like to be precise )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I wrote a simple SystemTap script(based on [syscalls_by_pid.stp](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/examples/process/syscalls_by_pid.stp)).
It produces output like this:

```
ProcessName          #SysCalls

munin-graph          38609 
munin-cron           8160  
fping                4502  
check_http_demo      2584  
check_nrpe           2045  
sh                   1836  
nagios               886   
sendmail             747   
smokeping            649   
check_http           571   
check_nt             376   
pcscd                216   
ping                 108   
check_ping           100   
crond                87    
stapio               69    
init                 56    
syslog-ng            27    
sshd                 17    
ntpd                 9     
hp-asrd              8     
hald-addon-stor      7     
automount            6     
httpd                4     
stap                 3     
flow-capture         2     
gam_server           2     

Total                61686
```

The script itself:

```
#! /usr/bin/env stap

#
# Print the system call count by process name in descending order.
#

global syscalls

probe begin {
  print ("Collecting data... Type Ctrl-C to exit and display results\n")
}

probe syscall.* {
  syscalls[execname()]++
}

probe end {
  printf ("%-20s %-s\n\n", "ProcessName", "#SysCalls")
  summary = 0
  foreach (procname in syscalls-) {
    printf("%-20s %-10d\n", procname, syscalls[procname])
    summary = summary + syscalls[procname]
  }
  printf ("\n%-20s %-d\n", "Total", summary)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **pstrace**  as said Jeff Foster to trace the system call.

Also, you can use strace and ltrace

**strace** - trace system calls and signals

**ltrace** - A library call tracer

Comment: I mean I need to know the summary of syscalls for **all** processes currently being executed by OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ptrace` to monitor all syscalls (see [here](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl2_ptrace.htm))

Comment: I think writing custom application is a bit complicated for this task, and ptrace() is not so lightweight, especially when run against all processes in system

Answer (score 1):

I believe [OProfile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/) can do this.

Comment: can't get OProfile run on my system, so I wrote a simple SystemTap script, see below.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a centralized way to monitor syscalls throughout the entire OS. Maybe do a `ptrace` on the `init` process and follow all children? But I don't know if that will work.

Your best bet is to write a patch to the kernel itself to do this. The closest thing to this that I've seen is a cgroup implementation for enforcing permissions on what syscalls can be executed at runtime. You can find the patch here:

https://github.com/luksow/syscalls-cgroup

It shouldn't be too much more work to throw a counter in there, from a kernel programming perspective.

Comment: I tried to run strace -fv -p 1, but it seems it doesn't attach to all processes that way.

Comment: to avoid patching the kernel I used SystemTap, see the script I've attached. Thanks for help. Actually, I can't believe that there's no such a counter in /proc/sys/ ... Can't even imagine a reason for this. Is there anyone who knows why they didn't implement it?

Comment: Looking at the code you posted - those aren't syscalls, those are applications/processes. A syscall is a kernel function exported to userland, such as setuid, capset, mount; see here for a list: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/dir_section_2.html

Comment: In the first column shown application names, in the second - number of syscalls called by these applications(without specifying names of those syscalls).